# I'm looking for a term, word or phase used to describe the important, but minute, details. Something along the lines of, "it's the little things"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Persons often say, "It's the little things". I'm looking for a word or term that would describe this feeling of a minute detail completing a whole.

Comment: *A mountain is composed of tiny grains of earth. The ocean is made up of tiny drops of water.* http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/s/swamisivan165766.html

Comment: Could you give us a sentence with a blank where the word would be? Context is always helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ***minutiae*** would work. Although minutiae can be trivial, very often they aren't, but rather each is a precise part of a whole.

> The small, precise, or trivial details of something:
>   *the minutiae of everyday life*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/minutiae)

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *[the devil is in the details](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/the-devil-is-in-the-details)* emphasizes the importance, but also the difficult aspects of the specifics of a situation

> The details of a matter are its most problematic aspect.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: "God is in the details" is also sometimes said.  Ngram is ambiguous as to which is more popular.